# Maximizing a given function?

Tags: optimization

I have a function as below, 
$f(\alpha) = \frac{{1 - \alpha }}{2}\ln \left( {1 + \frac{{AB}}{{B + \frac{{1 - \alpha }}{{C\alpha }}}}} \right)$, 
where $A$, $B$, $C$ are constant, and $0 < \alpha  < 1$ is a variable. Can someone give me a hint how to derive a value of $\alpha$ that maximizes the given function. 
I have tried to solve this way: 
$\frac{{df\left( \alpha  \right)}}{{d\alpha }} = 0$, 
but I could not get a closed form solution.

Thank you very much.
Best regards, Binh.

Comment: There is no closed form solution for the solution of $\frac{{df\left( \alpha  \right)}}{{d\alpha }} = 0$. If you have the values of $A,B,C$ use Newton for the solution. If you give me numbers, I shall show you how to proceed.